# If there were positive and negative masses similar to positive and negative charges, would there be some kind of gravitational magnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, coulombs-law

Coulomb's law is very similar to Newon's law of gravitation. But as we go deeper into electromagnetic phenomena we see that it is very complex compared to newtonian gravitation. For example if the charges are moving then Coulomb's law is not enough, we need additional terms that deal with magnetic forces.

**So is the existence of two different types of charges the reason for this complexity?** If there were two types of mass with same types of mass repelling one another while different types of mass attracting one another, would simple Newton's law of graviation be enough or would there be some kind of magnetic force?

**Also what would happen if there were only one type of mass but instead of attracting they repelled?** Is this case more complex then newonian gravitation?

Comment: Gravotomagnetism does exit already in general relativity.

Comment: *"Coulomb's law is very similar to Newon's law of gravitation"* - there's a *crucial* difference in the sign of the force, i.e., like electric charge repels while 'like' gravitational mass attracts.